# PHP/MySQL code won't insert userid and password into table

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, sessionid, login-script

I'm working on an assignment and can't seem to get my code to insert the userid and password into my "users" table. The input name is "userid" and "password" - I also used a hashing password example. For the sake of brevity, I left out the code that follows if($result == false). If you don't see any errors, then I will chalk it up to errors in my SQL table/host setup.

```
Thanks so much.  

<?php

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    require('constants.php');
    include_once('menu.php'); 

    //starts connection
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERID,PASSWORD,DB);

    if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`userid`, `password`) VALUES (?,?)";
        // PREPARED STATEMENTS
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc,$query);

        include('PasswordHash.php');
        $pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
        $hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword($password);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$userid,$hash);

        // execute query
        $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    else {
        //user successfully signed in
        //session the session value to the user id
        $_SESSION['uid']=$userid;
        //display the page
        include('displayChat.php');
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `mysqli_error()`?

http://us1.php.net/mysqli_error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest moving from mysqli_* to PDO.

I don't really use mysqli_* but this should work. If it doesn't, post all the code you're using to make it easier.
Also you were missing a bracket beside your `else {`

```
require 'constants.php';
include_once 'menu.php'; 

if( isset($_POST['register']) )
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(HOST,USERID,PASSWORD,DB);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare( $dbc, "INSERT INTO users (userid, password) VALUES ( :userid, :password )" );
    $stmt = mysqli_execute(':userid' =>$_POST['userid'], ':password' => $_POST['password']);

    include('PasswordHash.php');
    $pwdHasher = new PasswordHash(8, false);
    $hash = $pwdHasher->HashPassword($_POST['password']);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'ss',$_POST['userid'],$hash);

    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

} else {
    $_SESSION['uid']= $userid;

    include_once 'displayChat.php';
}
```